# What SSL Version Number works with Gmail's SMTP Server on Port 587?

Tags: python, email, openssl, smtp

I'm writing a simple SMTP Client to send an email with GMail's SMTP server. I am receiving the SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] error while trying to implement the STARTTLS command.
I checked my current version of OpenSSL: OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023, Version Number: 805306544.

#### Log:

```
python src/mail_server.py
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f17-20020ac84651000000b0042545901450sm257426qto.72 - gsmtp

250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.250.221.86]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/coffinw9/Documents/Georgia Tech/Intro to Networks/vs-code-workspace/python-learning/mail-server-lab/src/mail_server.py", line 42, in <module>
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=mailserver[0]) as ssock:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1046, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1317, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1000)
```

#### Code:

```
import socket
import time
import sys
import ssl

# Choose a mail server (e.g. Google mail server) and call it mailserver
mailserver = ('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

# Create socket called client_socket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
# Fill in start
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(mailserver)
# Fill in end

recv = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print(recv)
if recv[:3] != '220':
    print('220 reply not received from server.')

# Send HELO command and print server response.
heloCommand = f'EHLO {socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())}\r\n'
client_socket.send(heloCommand.encode())

recv1 = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# STARTTLS command needed to authenticate into server
STARTTLS_MSG = 'STARTTLS\r\n'
client_socket.send(STARTTLS_MSG.encode())
recv = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print(recv)

# Wrap the socket in SSL/TLS protocol
context = ssl.create_default_context()
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

with socket.create_connection(mailserver) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=mailserver[0]) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
sys.exit("Stopping for TLS")

... Rest of implementation ...
```

I have tried moving the SSL wrap after the STARTTLS, which is documented to be the correct way to start the TLS Session. But I'm still seeing the version error. I'm wondering if GMail uses a slightly different version of OpenSSL, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you writing your own client when there's already a perfectly fine `smtplib`?

Comment: It's a textbook assignment